# How to prevent WebStorm temp files constantly launch Meteor rebuilt

Tags: meteor, webstorm

Each time I write something into WebStorm IDE Meteor rebuilds. Even if I don't save the files. My computer becomes noisy and hot quickly.

I am looking for a way to prevent Meteor to watch WebStorm temp files.

Comment: Where are these files located? Is it the `.idea` folder?

Comment: at the root folder of my meteor project.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen when debugging your code? If yes, this must be a Live Edit [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7093). Try disabling Live Edit plugin - does it help?

Comment: I don't try yet debugging my code. It happens when I simply write my code.

Comment: I unchecked the plugin but Meteor is still rebuilding without saves.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the synchronization section of the [system settings page](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/system-settings.html) from their documentation

Here's what it says:

> Synchronization
>
> Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation
>   If this check box
>   is selected, all the files that were changed externally are reloaded
>   from disk when you switch to WebStorm from a different application, or
>   when you you switch to their editor tab.
>
> Save files on frame deactivation
>   If this check box is selected, all
>   modified files are auto saved when you switch from WebStorm to a
>   different application. Note that you cannot disable autosave
>   completely by turning off this and the following option. See Saving
>   and Reverting Changes.
>
> Save files automatically if application is idle for N seconds
>   If this
>   check box is selected, all modified files are auto saved at regular
>   time internals. See also, Saving and Reverting Changes.
>
> Use "safe write" (save changes to a temporary file first)
>   If this
>   check box is selected, a changed file is first saved in a temporary
>   file. If the save operation succeeds, the file being saved is replaced
>   with the saved file. (Technically, the original file is deleted and
>   the temporary file is renamed.)  Also, the ownership of such file
>   changes. If this check box is not selected, the ownership of a file
>   does not change, but all the advantages of safe write will be lost.

Try unchecking those checkboxes and see if that prevents some saves.

I had a similar problem in that WebStorm was constantly saving edits to Jade files, even after typing just one character, triggering a gulp watcher. Disabling the Live Edit plugin and unchecking these boxes worked for me. Since disabling Live Edit didn't work for you, maybe unchecking one or more of these boxes will fix it.

Comment: I have also unchecked Remote Hosts Access and Settiings Repository but still got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this meteor specific webstorm help [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-meteor.html). There is detailed description on how to configure live edit and code updating and how that would work together with meteor.